# How do I create a Linux N6 (with GPU) VM on Azure for Deep Learning applications?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, azure

When I try to do new Ubuntu Compute VM in East US or South Central US (the two with advertised GPU support), there is no option to select N6.

The only way to get N6 VM is to use the "Deep Learning toolkit for the DSVM" option, which is a Windows VM.

Is it possible to create a Linux N6 VM on Azure? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these requirements and you should see it in the list:

- Only Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is supported
- Make sure you are selecting HDD - SSD is not supported/working although local disk is SSD
- Choose any of these regions: East US, North Central US, South Central US, West Europe or Southeast Asia.